# Permalink to list all posts of particular post_type

Tags: wordpress

I would like to be able to list all same types of post in page. For example, http://mydomain.com/page should list all page type post, similarly http://mydomain.com/posts should list all blog entries.

What would be permalik to get as above.

KRish

Comment: You are asking 3-4 questions in one here @krishna - how to set up permalinks, how to display all posts, how to display all pages, etc. What have you tried/researched?

Comment: I want be able to list same type of post, for which I am looking any permalink exists. E.g. you you do http://domain.com/page should list all pages, similarly when you do http://domain.com/post, it should list all pages, and, while you do http://domain.com/custom_post_type, it should list all custom_post_type

Answer (score 0):

Create a page for each ('page' and 'posts') and you can choose what the permalink will be just under the title.

You'll then have to edit the page's HTML to display all pages and all posts. This should get you started:

List pages - http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages
Get posts - http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Write, that's way. But still, is permalink to list all blog entries?